# how to route dynamic page programmatic in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I needs to route page dynamically based on some scenario.

```
 { path: ':locale/:id', component: HomePageCategory    },
 { path: ':locale/:platform', component: PlatformPageCategory    },
 { path: ':locale/contact', component: ContactPageCategory    },
```

Above is my routing configuration. in that first and second was dynamic. i needs to archive above all the cases. i have written service based in canActivate.

but i needs to route page programmatic, like

```
router.navigate()
router.navigateByUrl()
```

can you please tell how to do that for this case.

Comment: The router will always resolve the first route matched. In your case, even if you navigate to, for example: `en/3` or `en/desktop`, the router will always match the first route, since it can't know that your id must be an integer for example, or that the platform must be something like `desktop/tablet/mobile` etc. As aworkaround, you could use query parameters instead of the second dynamic parameter.

Comment: Hi @BogdanB,   is any possibility was there to find the exact route page for programmatic routing?

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to have routes like that? Because it doesn't really make any sense. You could have something like `home/:locale/:id` ,  `platform/:locale` and `contact/:locale` . That would eliminate your problems.

Comment: Hi @BogdanB,   Yes mandatory. we are making internal application so localization we are including based on locale all the components will load and its dynamic. same like we had platform page  as like below      "www.abc.com/en/1", "www.abc.com/en/vscode", "www.abc.com/en/contact"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, i suggest doing the following:

1. Add a `root component` to your routing and get rid of the other routes.
   Something like this
   `{ path: ':locale/:param', component: RootComponent}`
2. Inside the `RootComponent`, subscribe to the router, and parse your dynamic parameters, choosing which component to render based on that.
3. `RootComponent`'s template should only contain a `<ng-container #host></ng-container>`,
   which will be used as the host element for your component to be rendered.
4. Render the component using `ComponentFactoryResolver` ( docs here : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader ).

Comment: i had another problem  can you please check on that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559962/external-file-loading-reference-loading-issue-due-to-dynamic-routing-in-angular